# LM2576 TI Simulation not working

Tags: voltage, integrated-circuit, power-electronics, simulation, buck

I have used the PSPICE model of [LM2576](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2576.pdf) IC from the Texas instruments but the simulation is giving me false results. I have used the exact same diagram from the datasheet but the IC is not working. I don't know what the problem and there are no parameters I can give to this IC which could be one reason. Kindly help me do a successful simulation of this IC.
[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to do the transient analysis in PSPICE not the DC operation point.

Comment: It is set in transient anylysis

Comment: But you didn't show us transient analysis results.

Comment: @G36 I have added that

Comment: Try to change C2 to 100uF and R1 to 10R and increased the simulation time to 10ms. What did you expect to see in the first 10nS?

Comment: Yes now I am getting a DC output of 3V. Is there any way I could edit the voltage out out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try increasing the time from 10ns to at least 10us. The time you set is very small and this time is not enough for the voltage to set up at the output.